# Loading paginated images in a facebook gallery

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, gallery, facebook-opengraph

I'm attempting to create a gallery by loading images from a facebook album.

However, I'm running into a problem where facebook has a limit of 25 images per page, and I can't work out a way to use the JSON paging response to collect further data.

Any advice on incorporating this response into my code would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

(function (gallery_id) {
    var title = $('h3'),
        thumbs = $('.thumbs');

    // album info
    $.getJSON('//graph.facebook.com/' + gallery_id + '?callback=?', function(json, status, xhr) {
      title.html('<a href="' + json.link + '">' + json.name + '</a> from ' + json.from.name);
    });

    // images
    $.getJSON('//graph.facebook.com/' + gallery_id + '/photos?callback=?', function(json, status, xhr) {
      var imgs = json.data;



      for (var i = 0, l = imgs.length - 1; i < l; i++) {
        $('<div><img src="' + imgs[i].images[3].source + '" data-img="' + imgs[i].images[0].source + '" data-fullsize="' + imgs[i].images[0].source + '"></div').appendTo(thumbs);
      }
       $('.thumbs').SuperBox();




    });
  })('406683109390041');
});
```

In use here: [vikingsofmiddleengland.co.uk/beta/gallery.html](http://www.vikingsofmiddleengland.co.uk/beta/gallery.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may increase the limit of photos by adding limit to the request  **//graph.facebook.com//album_id/photos/?limit=100**,
 
but if you have many photos, you should paginate with since and until parameters like this:
 **//graph.facebook.com/album_id/photos?limit=25&until=1298957761** where since and until parameter would be unix timestamp OR you can crawl for the next 50 photos through offset parameter 
**//graph.facebook.com/album_id/photos?limit=25&offset=50**   .

There are other ways of paginating between objects through graph api, you should look into this, [pagination with graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/)

then you may build a function to fetch next few photos. you can trigger it through a button or you can fetch them at a time interval or you can use callback function to re-request to the server.

Comment: Many thanks, that's a much better explanation than on the developer page!